# Range, Column Space, and Basis

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to clarify whether the following are true or not because I've seen different explanations from the textbook and my professor.

Given a linear transformation $T: \mathbb R^n \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ with a matrix representation $A$,

- The column space of $A$ is the span of the column vectors of $A$
- The range of $T$ is the column space of $A$
- A basis for the range of $T$ should include the linearly independent column vectors from $A$ (or is it the linearly independent column vectors from $A$ reduced to R.E.F?)

I've also read that the range of $T$ is the column space of $A$ in $\mathbb R^m$. If that is true, what exactly does that mean?

Comment: Regarding the third bullet, elementary row operations change the column space, so...

Answer (score 1):

- Yes; that's the definition of column space.
- Yes, because $\operatorname{Range}T=T(\mathbb R^n)$ and, since $T$ is linear, $T(\mathbb R^n)$ is the span of$$\bigl\{T(1,0,0,\ldots,0),T(0,1,0,\ldots,0)\ldots,T(0,0,0,\ldots,1)\bigr\},$$which is the column space of $A$.
- No. A basis of the range of $T$ is *any* basis of that space. It doesn't have to consist of some columns of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have been answered well by Professor Santos. On the third point, remember that bases are not unique. I can construct a basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the vectors $\{(2,0), (0,1)\}$ just as well as the standard basis vectors $\{(1,0), (0,1)\}$. As long as the vectors are linearly independent and span, they are a basis.